# OpenLayer 3 - modify features of Cluster layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

the following question was already raised on "OL3 Dev" but it has been moved  to StackOverflow to comply with the group policies.

I've been using OpenLayers 3 for some time and implemented a simple test application where I simulate the movement of several objects on a map. 
I use a Vector layer and a corresponding Vector source.

Let's say I have about 1000 features with a ol.geom.Point geometries that are updated every 20-30secs.

I can obtain pretty good results by modifying the geometry coordinates, the result is smooth and works ok.

Now I tried to use the Cluster functionality, to group closed features. Unfortunately in this case the result is very slow and irregular. 
I think the problem is due to the change() event being fired every time the geometry of a single feature is changed, so i was wondering:

is there a way to prevent the modification of a feature to be immediately taken into consideration by the Cluster, and fire it only at a specific interval?

Here below you can find two examples, the first without the Cluster source and the second with it.

1. No Cluster: http://jsfiddle.net/sparezenny/dwLpmqvc/

   ```
   var mySource =  new ol.source.Vector({
       features : new Array()
   });

   var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
       source: mySource,
       style: function(feature, resolution) {
                var myStyle = [new ol.style.Style({
                   image: new ol.style.Circle({
                     radius: 10,
                     stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                       color: '#fff'
                     }),
                     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                       color: '#3399CC'
                     })
                   })
               })];
              return myStyle;
     }
   });

   var map = new ol.Map({
           target: 'map',
           layers: [
             new ol.layer.Tile({
               source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
             }),
             myLayer
           ],
           view: new ol.View({
             center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
             zoom: 4
           })
   });

   var positions = new Array();

   function Mock(id, longitude, latitude){
           this.id=id;
           this.latitude=latitude;
           this.longitude=longitude;       
   };

   function updatePositions(mocks){
       var featuresToBeAdded = new Array();
       for (var i=0; i < mocks.length; i++){
           var mock = mocks[i];
           var id = mock.id;
           var previousPosition = positions[id];       
           var resultFeature;
           var position;
           // new
           if (previousPosition==undefined || previousPosition==null){
               position = ol.proj.transform([ mock.longitude, mock.latitude ],
                                                'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
               positions[id] = mock;
               resultFeature = new ol.Feature({
                   geometry: new ol.geom.Point(position)
               });
               featuresToBeAdded.push(resultFeature);
           }
           // update
           else{
               resultFeature  = positions[id].feature;
               positions[id] = mock;
               position = ol.proj.transform([ mock.longitude, mock.latitude ],
                                                'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
               resultFeature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(position);
           }
           positions[id].feature = resultFeature;
       }

       if (featuresToBeAdded.length>0){
           mySource.addFeatures(featuresToBeAdded);
       }
       //map.render();
   }

   var myMocks = new Array(1000);
   for (var i=0; i<1000; i++){
       myMocks[i] = new Mock(i, 
           37.41+(Math.random()>0.5?0.01:-0.01)*i, 
           8.82 +(Math.random()>0.5?0.01:-0.01)*i);
   }

   setInterval(
       function(){
           var j = Math.round(Math.random()*980);
           for (var i=0; i<20; i++){
               myMocks[j+i].latitude = myMocks[j+i].latitude + (Math.random()>0.5?0.01:-0.01);
               myMocks[j+i].longitude = myMocks[j+i].longitude + (Math.random()>0.5?0.01:-0.01);
           }
           console.debug("updatePositions..");
           updatePositions(myMocks);
   }, 5000);
   ```
2. Cluster: http://jsfiddle.net/sparezenny/gh7ox9nj/

   ```
   var mySource =  new ol.source.Vector({
       features : new Array()
   });

   var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
       distance: 10,
       source: mySource
   });

   var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
       source: clusterSource,
       style: function(feature, resolution) {
               var clusteredFeatures = feature.get('features');
               var size = feature.get('features').length;
                var myStyle = [new ol.style.Style({
                   image: new ol.style.Circle({
                     radius: 10,
                     stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                       color: '#fff'
                     }),
                     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                       color: '#3399CC'
                     })
                   }),
                   text: new ol.style.Text({
                     text: size.toString(),
                     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                       color: '#fff'
                     })
                   })
               })];
              return myStyle;
     }
   });

   var map = new ol.Map({
           target: 'map',
           layers: [
             new ol.layer.Tile({
               source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
             }),
             myLayer
           ],
           view: new ol.View({
             center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
             zoom: 4
           })
   });

   var positions = new Array();

   function Mock(id, longitude, latitude){
           this.id=id;
           this.latitude=latitude;
           this.longitude=longitude;       
   };

   function updatePositions(mocks){
       var featuresToBeAdded = new Array();
       for (var i=0; i < mocks.length; i++){
           var mock = mocks[i];
           var id = mock.id;
           var previousPosition = positions[id];       
           var resultFeature;
           var position;
           // new
           if (previousPosition==undefined || previousPosition==null){
               position = ol.proj.transform([ mock.longitude, mock.latitude ],
                                                'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
               positions[id] = mock;
               resultFeature = new ol.Feature({
                   geometry: new ol.geom.Point(position)
               });
               featuresToBeAdded.push(resultFeature);
           }
           // update
           else{
               resultFeature  = positions[id].feature;
               positions[id] = mock;
               position = ol.proj.transform([ mock.longitude, mock.latitude ],
                                                'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
               resultFeature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(position);
           }
           positions[id].feature = resultFeature;
       }

       if (featuresToBeAdded.length>0){
           mySource.addFeatures(featuresToBeAdded);
       }
       //map.render();
   }

   var myMocks = new Array(1000);
   for (var i=0; i<1000; i++){
       myMocks[i] = new Mock(i, 
           37.41+(Math.random()>0.5?0.01:-0.01)*i, 
           8.82 +(Math.random()>0.5?0.01:-0.01)*i);
   }

   setInterval(
       function(){
           var j = Math.round(Math.random()*980);
           for (var i=0; i<20; i++){
               myMocks[j+i].latitude = myMocks[j+i].latitude + (Math.random()>0.5?Math.random()*0.01:-Math.random()*0.01);
               myMocks[j+i].longitude = myMocks[j+i].longitude + (Math.random()>0.5?Math.random()*0.01:-Math.random()*0.01);
           }
           console.debug("updatePositions..");
           updatePositions(myMocks);
   }, 5000);
   ```

As you can see I have 1000 features and I try to update the positions of 20 of them every 5 seconds. 
In the first case the interaction with the map is smooth, whilst in the second case it often stops or slow down.

Any clue or advise about how to avoid that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is an old link now, but as I've encountered exactly the same issue, I thought I'd post my work-around.

The idea is to cripple the offending event handler in the cluster source, and only fire that same code every frame render.

Note that the code as presented:

1. Is really quite a hack, as it's messing about with private functions.
2. Because of the above, it may well need modifying for different non-debug builds.
3. Uses a newer version of OL3 than the OP (see also point 2!).

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/o7brsw6o/)

```
if (ol.source.Cluster.prototype.onSourceChange_)
{
    // Make a new pointer to the old sourceChange function.
    ol.source.Cluster.prototype.newSourceChange =
        ol.source.Cluster.prototype.onSourceChange_;

    // Nuke the old function reference.
    ol.source.Cluster.prototype.onSourceChange_ = function() {};
}
if (ol.source.Cluster.prototype.Ra)
{
    // As above, but for non-debug code.
    ol.source.Cluster.prototype.newSourceChange = 
        ol.source.Cluster.prototype.Ra;
    ol.source.Cluster.prototype.Ra = function() {};
}

// Later on..
map.on('postrender', clusterSource.newSourceChange, clusterSource);
```

As you can see, this comfortably handles the 1000 features even with a 100ms update time.